# Compile error: Cannot find symbol AudioEffect::setParameter in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to set `AudioEffect` parameters by `AudioEffect::setParameter`, but it gives compile error in Android Studio.

Here is my code:

```
import android.media.audiofx.Equalizer;
...
private Equalizer mEqualizer = null;
mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0,  mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
mEqualizer.setParameter(0,0);
```

This worked in my old Eclipse project; now I'm using an new AS project, but it gives an error : *cannot find symbol method setParameter(int,int)*

I also tried call `setParameter()` by AudioEffect object:

```
import android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect;

AudioEffect effect = null;
effect = new AudioEffect(AudioEffect.EFFECT_TYPE_EQUALIZER,
                AudioEffect.EFFECT_TYPE_NULL,
                0,
                0);

effect.setParameter(0,0);
```

Then get the same error.

Here are source codes from Android SDK:

android-sdk\android-23\android\media\audiofx\Equalizer.java:

```
public class Equalizer extends AudioEffect {
```

android-sdk\android-23\android\media\audiofx\AudioEffect.java:

```
public class AudioEffect {
...
    public int setParameter(int param, int value) throws IllegalStateException {
        byte[] p = intToByteArray(param);
        byte[] v = intToByteArray(value);
        return setParameter(p, v);
    }
```

Does anyone know why can't I call this method in Android Studio? (but it works in Eclipse).

Android Studio version 2.1.2
Using Android SDK 23 (also tried SDK 22 and 21, the same error).

Comment: Android doesn't use the double colon of Java 8, so I'm not sure why you included that in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html), there is no method `setParameters` in class `AudioEffect`, neither there I can see type `EFFECT_TYPE_NULL`. I checked in my sdk as well. You must be using outdated code. Please refactor it to latest SDK. [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) have a method [setParamters(String keyValuePairs)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setParameters(java.lang.String)). It can be of your use.

Comment: Thank you, I think you're right. Even though I don't see any "deprecated" in AudioEffect.java and this still works on Eclipse with SDK 23.
I'll try other setting method which declared on document.