# Noozxoide EIZO-rewire™ PRO crashing under Android 11

Tags: android, sdk, apk, signal-processing, android-11

since I´ve downloaded the Android 11 update (Samsung Galaxy S10e; also tested with Android SDK´s Emulator running Android 11, same results), the DSP app "Noozxoide EIZO-rewire™ PRO" is always crashing when started. I know that this app was developed for Android 4.0, but it was even working properly on Android 10. I decided to download Android SDK  to test in on VM and look at the logcat.
I would like to get the app working because it improves the audio quality perfectly and I don´t know any similar app like this one. I wanted to contact the developers of the app but their e-mail adress does not exist anymore.
I don´t have any experience with developing apk´s, but maybe someone can help me :)
I have already read some logcat explanations and guide to migrating apps to Android 11 on developer.android but it didn´t really help me with this.

Maybe can someone explain to me what´s happening in this logcat part:

```
2021-02-24 20:21:19.648 10997-10997/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.noozxoidelabs.eizo.rewirepro, PID: 10997
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.setParameter [class [B, class [B]
    at com.noozxoidelabs.eizo.rewirepro.VSPCoreEngine.updateDsp(VSPCoreEngine.java:231)
    at com.noozxoidelabs.eizo.rewirepro.VSPCoreEngine$4.onCallStateChanged(VSPCoreEngine.java:129)
    at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub.lambda$onCallStateChanged$10(PhoneStateListener.java:1185)
    at android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$6czWSGzxct0CXPVO54T0aq05qls.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.setParameter [class [B, class [B]
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1693)
    at com.noozxoidelabs.eizo.rewirepro.VSPCoreEngine.updateDsp(VSPCoreEngine.java:226)
    at com.noozxoidelabs.eizo.rewirepro.VSPCoreEngine$4.onCallStateChanged(VSPCoreEngine.java:129) 
    at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub.lambda$onCallStateChanged$10(PhoneStateListener.java:1185) 
    at android.telephony.-$$Lambda$PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub$6czWSGzxct0CXPVO54T0aq05qls.run(Unknown Source:6) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Thanks in advance

PS: sorry for my misstakes in English :)

Answer (score 1):

**From the Google Play Store comments for that app, support is no longer available, and due to framework code changes won't work on modern Android**

Similar to: [Compile error: Cannot find symbol AudioEffect::setParameter in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37803013/295004)

A quick check of the source shows that in old version of Android:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5bb8f80/media/java/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.java

No annotation was on `setParameter(...)`

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android11-d1-release/media/java/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.java

While in newer ones the `setParameter(...)` functions is now hidden by `@TestApi` and throw an exception if not initialized correctly.

Any fix will require developer to update code.

Comment: It is not officially supported, but the patched version works well in newer Android systems. I am using it on Android 14. I am placing below how to get it installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution you're looking for. I downloaded an app from the Play Store called App Cloner, and ran Noozxoide through this program to create a cloned apk. The cloned app installed perfectly and worked fine on Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the end is the beginning for me. I am returning to Noozxoide EIZO-rewire™ PRO as you are probably trying to do.

I Confirm that the Noozxoide EIZO-rewire™ PRO v2.0.1.18 Patched mod Works in My Samsung S21 Ultra with the One UI 6.0, Android 14.

Getting and installing it is a little bit tricky:

1. Use Telegram to download the APK from this bot: https://t.me/EIZOBot
2. The App is password protected, to get the password, click on the password button of the Telegram bot. You need to subscribe to the YT Channel of the author and send a screenshot to the Telegram Bot. In a few hours, you will get the password.
3. If you are installing the app on Android 14, you will need to follow [these instructions](https://xdaforums.com/t/howto-install-old-apps-unsupported-by-the-one-ui-6-0-firmware-android-14.4638182/), otherwise, you won't be able to install the APK file.
4. Follow the configuration steps described [here](https://xdaforums.com/t/premium-sound-noozxoide-eizo-rewire-tm-pro-2-0-1-18-e-1-0-0-12-noozy-link.2039716/).

Finally pure eargasm in rootless Android 14!!!!! Not at the level of Viper4Android, but still better than Wavelet and Poweramp EQ, and without the brutal delay of rootlessJamesDSP.